# Quantitative Comparisons of Phylogenetic trees

Tags: bioinformatics

I am working on a broad phylogenomic analysis of proteins involved in one particular cellular process.  I have constructed a phylogenetic tree for each protein.  I am now working on comparing those trees in order to extract categories (i. e., allele a of protein a occurs most frequently with allele b of protein b, etc.).  I have attempted to construct a super tree using clann, but the tree is extremely difficult to interpret.  I would therefore like to carryout a quantitative comparison (and subsequent categorisation) of each each tree, but it is unclear to me how to even begin this analysis.  Is there a standardised method for comparison of phylogenetic trees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether it's exactly what you need, but there are formal algorithms for tree comparison.

There are basically two approaches: one utilizing tree lengths (branch score distance) and the other one dealing with topologies only (symmetric-difference metric): details and references can be found in the [manual to treedist from the phylip-package](http://evolution.genetics.washington.edu/phylip/doc/treedist.html), which implements both.

[PAUP*](http://paup.csit.fsu.edu/Cmd_ref_v2.pdf) has a command under the same name (treedist), which calculates the symmetric-difference metric only. This metric is very intuitive: it describes the total number of partitions (= splits) present only on one of the two trees.